# "CSRF Token Missing" in Django - {% csrf_token %} has been included

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-csrf, csrf-token

I have been trying to make a simple login page, and my form is submitting, however, I keep getting csrf failure. I had tried to put the tag in several places, but nothing works.

I have included the tag in different places, used different posts to change small things, but nothing worked. The first is my template html, and it loads. The latter is the view.py file, which should just render a view.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <title>Login Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Login Page</h1>
    
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        


        <div class="form-group">
            {% csrf_token %}
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input style = "max-width: 50%;" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
          <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {% csrf_token %}
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
          <input style = "max-width: 50%;" type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        
        <button href="/verify" style = "margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 25%; padding-right: 30px; padding-left: 30px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <button style = "margin-top: 30px; margin-left: 25%; padding-right: 30px; padding-left: 30px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

def LogIn(request):
    
    template = loader.get_template('login.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render())

def verify(request):
    pass
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <title>Login Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Login Page</h1>
    
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        


        <div class="form-group">
            {% csrf_token %}
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input style = "max-width: 50%;" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
          <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {% csrf_token %}
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
          <input style = "max-width: 50%;" type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        
        <button href="/verify" style = "margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 25%; padding-right: 30px; padding-left: 30px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <button style = "margin-top: 30px; margin-left: 25%; padding-right: 30px; padding-left: 30px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add  *@csrf_protect* decorator to your view functions

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

@csrf_protect
def my_view(request):
   ...
```